# HTML based workflow/journey designer component for use in SaaS website

Tags: c#, html, css, .net, workflow

I am looking for recommendations on a journey or workflow UI designer that can combine triggers, conditional logic and actions to create workflows in a SaaS website.

I am looking for a design canvas of sorts with drag and drop features to move components around and edit the settings of each block.

If you have ever done any marketing automation work, its the designer that would be used to create the user journey.